# (Arithmetic Series) If the sum of first 10 terms is 120 and the first 20 terms is 840, what is the sum of the first 30 terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For the series of an arithmetic sequence.

$S_{10} = 120$

$S_{20} = 840$

$S_n = ?$

How do I calculate this?

Comment: Approach it with the definition of an arithmetic series. What is the general form of an arithmetic series and its sum? What would be the sum of the first 10 terms in a general arithmetic series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $S_{10}$, $a_1$ + $a_{10}$ $= \frac{120}{5} = 24$

For $S_{20}$, $a_1$ + $a_{20}$ $= \frac{840}{10} = 84$

$d = \frac{84 - 24}{10} = 6$

$S_n = \frac{n}{2}(a_1 + a_{nth})$

$120 = 5(2a_1 + 9d)$

$840 = 10(2a_1 + 19d)$

$120 = 10a_1 + 45d$..........eq$1$

$840 = 20a_1 + 190d$.........eq$2$

$720 = 10a_1 + 870$

$a_1 = -15$

$S_n = \frac{n}{2}(-15 + (6(n-1) - 15))$

$S_n = \frac{n}{2}(6(n-1) - 30)$

$$S_n = \frac{n}{2}(6n - 36)$$

$$S_{30} = 15(180 - 36) = 2160$$

Comment: @N. F. Taussig Yes, two wrongs made a right. Well spotted.

Answer (score 3):

With $a_n=dn+b$, note that $a_{11}+\ldots +a_{20}=a_1+\ldots +a_{10}+ 10\cdot d$ and $a_{21}+\ldots +a_{30}=a_{11}+\ldots +a_{20}+10\cdot d$. In short,
$$ S_{20}-S_{10}=S_{10}+10d\\S_{30}-S_{20}=S_{20}-S_{10}+10d$$
Now eliminate the $10d$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

The average of terms $1$ to $30$ is the same as the average of terms $11$ to $20$. So the sum of terms $1$ to $30$ is $3$ times the sum of terms $11$ to $20$ (because there are $3$ times as many terms). So

$S_{30} = 3(S_{20}-S_{10})$

Answer (score 1):

Recall the following formula.

$$S_n = \frac{n(u_1+u_n)}{2} = \frac{n(u_1+u_1+(n-1)d)}{2} = \frac{n(2u_1+(n-1)d)}{2}$$

Apply them to $S_{10}$ and $S_{20}$.

$$1) \text{ }S_{10} = 120 \implies \frac{10(2u_1+(10-1)d)}{2} = \color{blue}{5(2u_1+9d) = 120}$$

$$2)\text{ }S_{20} = 840 \implies \frac{20(2u_1+(20-1)d)}{2} = \color{purple}{10(2u_1+19d) = 840}$$

Simplify both equations.

$$3)\text{ }5(2u_1+9d)) = 120 \implies \color{blue}{2u_1+9d = 24}$$

$$4)\text{ }10(2u_1+19d) = 840 \implies \color{purple}{2u_1+19d = 84}$$

Subtract $3)$ and $4)$ to eliminate $2u_1$.

$$-10d = -60 \implies \boxed{d = 6}$$

Plug in $d = 6$ in either of the equations to get $u_1$.

$$2u_1+9d = 24 \implies 2u_1+9(6) = 24 \implies \boxed{u_1 = -15}$$

Now, rewrite the original formula with $d = 6$ and $u_1 = -15$. Keep in mind there are multiple ways to write the answer.

$$S_n = \frac{n(2u_1+(n-1)d)}{2}$$

$$S_n = \frac{n(2(-15)+(n-1)6)}{2}$$

$$\boxed{S_n = \frac{n(-30+6n-6)}{2} = \frac{n(6n-36)}{2} = n(3n-18) = 3n(n-6)}$$

Now, the formula can be used to calculate any $S_n$, be it $S_{30}$ or any other $n$ asked for.